# How to make Selenium wait

Tags: python, selenium

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

    login = 'somemail@gmail.com'
    password = 'anypass'
    mail = 'somemail2.ekb@gmail.com'
    text = 'Hello world!'

    driver= webdriver.Firefox()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    driver.get("https://mail.google.com/")
    assert 'Gmail' in driver.title
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'identifier').send_keys(login + Keys.RETURN)

    # time.sleep(5)

    result = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
    elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
    elem.send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)
```

This program has the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input class="whsOnd zHQkBf" name="password" type="password"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

> **Hi Here is the problem. Without time.sleep(5) I get exeption ('is not reachable by keyboard' or 'cant be scrolled or smth like that').**

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

Could you please edit your post to explain your problem better? Explain what you want to do, exactly what errors you are getting, etc.

Also your formatting isn't great, could you put the errors in separate code blocks to make it more readable?

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the line `presence_of_element_located` by `element_to_be_clickable`, because the Selenium seems to have loaded the element but it is not selectable yet, possibly due to the sliding animation google mail plays.

Comment: element to be clickable wait includes presense wait + click wait. please read the doc for thsi wait.